# how to hide progressview when webview load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiprogressbar

hi I want to ask a simple question how I can hide or disable progress bar when `UIWebView` load, I add `ProgressBar` as `subview` of `webview` . I did it by using this way in the method below, but it can't help me because every site take different time to load because of their content size so kindly tell me how I can hide or remove the `ProgressBar` when any site load in `webview`

```
- (void)makeMyProgressBarMoving {  

    float actual = [threadProgressView progress];  

    if (actual < 1) {  
        threadProgressView.progress = actual + 0.2;  
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  
    }  
    else
    {
        threadProgressView.hidden = YES;
        threadValueLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add delegate to UIWebView
For adding progress bar :-
Web view delegate method :-

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    threadProgressView.hidden = NO;
}
```

For Removing progress bar :-
Web view delegate method :-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    threadProgressView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: i added the progress bar as subview of webivew

Comment: then you can use addSubView on hidden=NO and removeFromSuperView on hidden=YES;

Comment: dude one another question i wanted to ask you i am working on a project i am creating a photo gallary same as like in iphone photo gallary in which i added customs buttons on scroll view and i set the pictures as background on these buttons and when someone click on any of these pictures it will show the larger images on next view controller. i mean to say is it the right way that i am adding images in scrollview using buttons

Comment: there are many third party libraries available, which will make your work easier. Visit http://www.cocoacontrols.com/, here just search and you will find any libraries free. Also, you can go with way you told, but remember to reduce size of image before placing to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Check your webview is loaded completly or not.

```
if(!yourWebView.loading)
{
   [yourProgress removeFromSuperView];
}
```

> **loading**
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the receiver is done loading
>   content. (read-only) `@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isLoading) BOOL loading` >
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If YES, the receiver is still loading content; otherwise, NO.
>   Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

**or**

You can implement the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method of UIWebView.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [yourProgress removeFromSuperView];
}
```

> **webViewDidFinishLoad**:
>
> Sent after a web view finishes loading a frame.
>   `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> webView
>
> ```
> The web view has finished loading.
> ```
>
> Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Refer [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html),[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details